# Few entries from select multiple option going as empty in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a form in which a user enters the data and it gets stored in the database. The problem is few entries in the "events column" which is a select multiple option are going as empty while some are not.
I am not sure whether it is a server issue for something is wrong in the code. Any help is appreciated!

Edited Register.html

```
 <form name="myform" action="check.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" name="name" required>
</div>

     <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required>
</div>

        <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Email">Mobile:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Enter Mobile " name="mobile" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="College">College:</label>
  <select id="cll" class="form-control" name="coll" required>
    <option value="IITM">IITM</option>
    <option value="IINTM">IINTM</option>
    <option value="Indraprastha">Indraprastha</option>
    <option value="Alumni">Alumni</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="College">Course:</label>
  <select id="cour" class="form-control" name="course" required>
    <option value="BBA">BBA</option>
    <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
    <option value="B.Com">B.Com</option>
    <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
    <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
  </select>
</div>

   <div class="form-group">
  <label for="College">College:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="college" placeholder="Enter College Name" name="college" required>
</div>

<div class="radio">
<label><input type="checkbox" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="q1" id="production" value="individual">Individual</label>
```

Group

```
<div id="productionSettings">
  <label for="sell">Individual Events</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="indi" name="events[]" multiple required>
    <option value="Solo Singing">Solo Singing</option>
    <option value="Solo Dance">Solo Dance</option>
    <option value="Beat Boxing">Beat Boxing</option>
    <option value="Mono Acting">Mono Acting</option>
    <option value="Photography">Photography</option> 
    <option value="Just a minute">Just a minute</option>  
  </select>
</div>
  <div id="alphaSettings">
  <label for="sell">Group Events</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="events[]" id="grp" multiple required>
    <option value="Group Singing">Group Singing</option>
    <option value="Nach Baliye">Nach Baliye</option>
    <option value="Ad Mad">Ad Mad</option>
    <option value="Pubg Tournament">Pubg Tournament</option>
    <option value="Pictionary">Pictionary</option>
    <option value="Rangoli">Rangoli</option>
    <option value="Nukkad Natak">Nukkad Natak</option>
    <option value="Cooking Without Fire">Cooking Without Fire</option>
    <option value="Quiz">Quiz</option>
    <option value="Murder Investigation">Murder Investigation</option>
    <option value="Mr And Miss Fiesta">Mr And Miss Fiesta</option>
    <option value="IPL Auction">IPL Auction</option>
    <option value="Group Dance">Group Dance</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="nunSettings" style="display: none">
 </div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
```

Edited store.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "iitmfies_admin", "pass", "iitmfies_first");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$college2=$_POST['coll'];
$events = array();

$events=$_POST['events'];

$ev2=implode(',', $events);
$_SESSION["eventsname"]=$ev2;
$key = uniqid();
$_SESSION["unique"] = "$key";
$q1 = $_POST['q1'];
if(empty($q1)){
$q1="abc";
}
if($college2!=='Others')
{
$college=$_POST['coll'];
$course=$_POST['course'];
}
else{
$college=$_POST['college'];
$course="null";
}
if ($q1!== "abc")
{

$select = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `email` FROM `person2` WHERE `email` = '$email'") or exit(mysqli_error($link));
if(mysqli_num_rows($select)) {
header('location: err.php');
exit('This email is already being used');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO person2 (name, email, mobile, college, course, events, entry, unkey) VALUES ('$name','$email','$mobile','$college','$course', '$ev2', '$q1', '$key')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

} else{

}   
}else
{
 $select = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `email` FROM `person3` WHERE `email` = '$email'") or exit(mysqli_error($link));
if(mysqli_num_rows($select)) {
header('location: err.php');
exit('This email is already being used');
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO person3 (name, email, mobile, college, course, unkey) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$mobile','$college','$course','$key')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

} else{

}   
}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: options value should be setted. something like `<option value="group_dance">Group Dance</option>`

Comment: Sure! ill try adding this!

Comment: What happens if user B enters an email address while user A is checking to see if that same email address exists?

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to set a value in your options (select)

Comment: Sure, ill try this. I read somewhere that it is optional so I didn't.

Comment: still getting empty entries

Answer (score 0):

You have to give values to all your  tags as below.

e.g.

```
<select class="form-control" id="indi" name="events[]" multiple required>
    <option value="Solo Singing">Solo Singing</option>
    <option value="Solo Dance">Solo Dance</option>
    <option value="Beat Boxing">Beat Boxing</option>
    <option value="Mono Acting">Mono Acting</option>
    <option value="Photography">Photography</option> 
    <option value="Just a minute">Just a minute</option>  
</select>
```

**EDIT :-**  SKIP empty/null values from "events" array.

```
$events = $_POST['events'];
foreach ( $events as $key => $value )
{
    if( trim($value) != '' )
    {
        $ev2 = implode(',', $events);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is that most of the values are getting stored but some are not?

Comment: Have you tried with `<option value="value1">` in select? If tried then is it still happening?

Comment: still getting empty entries

Comment: Why are you assigning same `name="events[]"` to both select inputs. Give them different names i.e. `name="indievents[]"` and `name="grpevents[]"`.

Comment: but I have to store them under same column.

Comment: @user2416229 Can you please update your latest tried code in question. So we can further see where is the problem.

Comment: @user2416229 I have updated my answer. Is this what you want.?

Comment: why would the value be empty when I have provided "required" in the html?

Comment: @user2416229. Please let me know what is the datatype of events column field in your database.? And which column values you are getting empty? Also if you select all events, try `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST['events']);` and see what you are getting.